# iOS: if I regenerate provisioning profile after adding a new capability, what will happen to an existing APNS capability?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have an iOS app featuring push notifications. I need to add a new app capability (associated domains) and regenerate my provisioning profiles. What will happen to push notifications? Am I required to do anything else? Thanks.

Comment: No it has no effect on APNS , because APNS is AppId Based so if the App id same regeneration of provisioning profiles doesn't have effect to notification

Comment: off-topic: how do you regenerate provisioning profiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it has no effect on APNS , because APNS is AppId Based so if the App id same regeneration of provisioning profiles doesn't have effect to notification.